# In LaTeX is there a way to include the filename of a graphic into a caption?

Tags: graphics, latex, caption

I have a LaTeX document with a large number of drawings included from external files with `\includegraphics{bla.pdf}`.  The drawings are done in Inkscape.  This all works fine.  However sometimes it is hard to keep track of all the drawings and their source files.  Hence I'm looking for a way to include the source file name, in the example `bla.pdf`, into the caption.  Not being a LaTeX expert I haven't found a way to automatically access the filename string from the caption.  Using Google-foo didn't yield a result either.  Is there an existing way to refer to the filename and include it in the caption, like `\caption{A fancy drawing of bla (\filename}`?

Comment: Are you aware of [Tex, LaTeX and friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com)? Latex question are still on topic here, but you may get better or faster answers there.

Comment: If you could give us a small example of what you're currently doing, we might be able to come up with a tailor-made solution...

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the image filename by patching a part of the nested calls inside `\includegraphics`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Gin@setfile}% <cmd>
  {\ProvidesFile}% <search>
  {\xdef\imgfilename{#3}\ProvidesFile}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Image: \imgfilename}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`\imgfilename` will contain the filename used in `\includegraphics` only *after* it's used.

Answer (score 0):

Redefine `\includegraphics`. For the case of no arguments (width=3cm, scale=2 or something like this) we have

```
\let \saveinclude \includegraphics
\def \includegraphics#1{\def\filename{#1}\saveinclude{#1}}
```

The use

```
\includegraphics{bla.pdf}
\caption{A fancy drawing of bla (\filename)}
```

Comment: What if I have arguments? I also have include images inside of custom commands in the preamble.